# selecting a TIA - and using it for 60dB dynamic range

Tags: amplifier, photodiode, laser

**before entering in to problem:**

my application is a laser pulse detection, in this process when a laser pulse falls on photo diode it generates current, for which i need a  Trans Impedance Amplifier (TIA) (i read literature on benefits TIA have like `SNR` improvement and `response time`)to convert that current to voltage

**my pulse characteristics:**

`pulse width` `min`:10ns `max`:150ns `rise/fall time`:2ns `pulse to pulse width`:22uS

**How i selected the TIA**

key parameters: `BW` - bandwidth and `SR` - Slew Rate

from this [literature](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/all-aboard-/4424573/Rule-of-Thumb--1--The-bandwidth-of-a-signal-from-its-rise-time) i found my BW can be calculated by formula

`BW`=0.35/(`rise time`)=0.35/5ns=`70MHz`

Now slew rate is to be calculated

`SR` = 2 * 3.14* `BW` * `Vp` = 2 * 3.14* 70MHz *5V = 2198V/us

So Matching both these parameters is  TIA [OPA659](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa659.pdf) from TI

EDIT:

with comments from experts about slew rate i have changed my TIA to [THS3001](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/ths3001.pdf) which has high slew rate and a CFA, (a point to note, even though the settling time of above CFA is 40ns i observed it to offer proper gain with out distorting pulse of `10ns` in simulation ), when i tried to use very high BW and very high SR opamps like LMH5401 i found the opamp design to be complex due to fluctuation in common mode voltage and to be very prone to noise in simulation itself.

**How to design a 60dB range TIA ?**

now my  problem statement has become much complex

> my pulse electrical characteristics are expected to be `Imin` 50nA
>   and `Imax` 50mA

EDIT:

as the specifications are stringent and after realizing the problem of noise gain explained by Andy

> i came to Imin 100nA and Imax 10mA

Comment: 0.175 GHz is 175 MHz -> you have 70 MHz above

Comment: @placeholder sorry for the mistake, rise time for now is  5ns

Comment: Re: 60 dB of dynamic range.  Current is an amplitude, dB is power (amplitude squared.) 50 nA to 50 mA is 120 dB.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold of course i want to achieve atleast 60dB so that i can break my current range to 2 channel, i dont think any TIA can achieve 120dB, for now i am breaking my head even to achieve 60dB exactly

Comment: @GeorgeHerold you can give some useful comments here i feel http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237600/complete-noise-analysis-to-find-the-minimum-detectable-signal-of-a-tia?noredirect=1#comment518735_237600

Comment: @kakeh, there are books written about photo diode front ends.  Read some of those.  Phil Hobb's is one of the better ones.  Here's an article by him from 2001.  http://electrooptical.net/www/frontends/frontends.pdf

Comment: i have gone through that, but in his suggestion of cascode i have to use a high speed BJT of 1Ghz, do we have such ???, may be he is dealing with non -pulsed light, more over my sensor which is highly capable and application oriented restricts me in a way that i will be able to use one end of photo diode the other end is already tied up to Vbias and comes a complete TO package,find it here http://www.excelitas.com/downloads/dts_harlid.pdf, so i cannot go for other Hobbs techiniques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bandwidth you have calculated is not considering the harmonics of the pulse. Consider that the pulse is 14ns long with inbuilt 2ns rise and fall repeating every 24 ns i.e. a symmetrical waveform. That has a fundamental of about 41 MHz but if you are interested in accuracy of the pulse shape then you should go for an op-amp with ten times this bandwidth.

As for slew rate, if your biggest output signal is (say) 2V p-p then it has to be able change 2V in 2ns = 1000 V/us. Now, onto the main show-stopper.

A 1,000,000:1 range of input currents is really optimistic for a conventional TIA because noise will be a problem for low signals (50 nA) but there are some tricks you can do to improve the basic design such as bootstrapping: -

[image]

Note the JFET addition to the standard TIA circuit - in effect it reduces the self-capacitance of the photodiode and solves (to a large extent) the inherent noise problem due to photodiode self-capacitance (see [**this**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjqxYb9o6LMAhULK8AKHQwvBhAQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linear.com%2Fdocs%2F16998&usg=AFQjCNEcYQH7lp7E5CNXajYQVA1R_6DwTw&sig2=bjYXodEc6OtZXjrBtXKZsA&cad=rja) article for more details and [**this**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/large-photodiode-capacitance) SE answer also).

However, the 50mA Imax requirement is unfeasible (maybe you mean 50 uA). The 50 mA has to be sunk/sourced by the op-amp's output and this will significantly affect the choice of available devices. I doubt that you will find an appropriate device but maybe you have a cunning plan?

Consider also what feedback resistor value you'll need to produce a change in output of (say) 2V. 2V/0.05A = 40 ohms. What will be the output amplitude when 50 nA is applied? I calculate 2 uV and that signal is totally embedded in noise. Why will it be embedded in noise - consider the input noise spec for the op-amp - maybe it's 3 nV / \$\sqrt{Hz}\$. A TIA having a bandwidth of 400 MHz will produce 60 uV RMS of noise at the output. Do the math - the spread of your limits cannot be met with anything I know of.

If you do want to detect 50 nA you will want the feedback resistor to be much higher than 40 ohms. 40 ohms produces an output of 2 uV in a noise of 60 x 6.6 uVp-p. The 6.6 (sigma) number converts RMS gaussian noise to p-p noise with a confidence factor of 99.9%. So the output noise will be 400 uVp-p and, because of this, you will want your smallest signal to be (say) ten times this value at 4 mVp-p.

A 4mV output change from a 50nA input change implies a feedback resistor value of 80 kohm (not 40 ohm). But this raises the problem of the photodiode capacitance - at 100 MHz a 12pF cap has an impedance of 133 ohms. This capacitance and the 80k feedback resistor amplify the op-amps internal noise by a factor of ~600. In other words you cannot asssume that the photodiode's self capacitance is negligible. It is the "total player" in defining the noise you will get. My previous "simplified" analysis assumed the op-amp is unity gain but it isn't. The 3dB point is \$\frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$ where R = 80k and C = 12pF i.e. F = 165 kHz. In other words from 165 kHz upwards the noise gain of the op-amp rises by 6 dB per octave and at 100 MHz the noise gain (as previously mentioned) is 600 and your TIA idea is toast!

There are some mitigations; the op-amp doesn't have infinite bandwidth so although the noise gain rises from 165 kHz it won't hit a peak of 600 at 100 MHz because if it did your op-amp would have a gain-bandwidth product of 60 GHz and they haven't been made yet.

So, if you say that a decent op-amp has a GBWP of 1 GHz, at 100 MHz the noise gain can never be more than ten. At 10 MHz the noise gain could be 100 but this is determined by the 12 pF and 80 kohm feedback resistor i.e. noise gain will actually be: -

\$1 + \dfrac{80,000}{X_C}\$ = 61

This is something like what your noise gain is going to look like spectrally: -

[image]

\$C_{sh}\$ is the photodiodes shunt capacitance i.e. the 12 pF. \$C_{i}\$ is the input capacitance of the op-amp (not negligible of course and adds to the problem). \$R_{f}\$ and \$C_{f}\$ is the feedback resistor and any capacitance in parallel with it (including parasites).

Somewhere in the middle of the raised portion of the graph is 10 MHz. Maybe consider 20 MHz as a spot frequency for examination; open loop gain might be 50 so this is going to be the noise gain limit. What about 5 MHz - the 1+R/Xc ratio will be about 31 and this is going to be the limit i.e. no longer dependent on the open loop gain.

It looks to me like the noise gain is peaking about 10 MHz and is still going to be a big problem for a 50nA input signal and a 80 kohm feedback resistor.

The trouble is, you have to increase the feedback resistor to bring your signal out from the noise and by the looks of it by something like ten times and, this causes another problem. 800 kohm and maybe 1pF of parasitic capacitance in parallel gives a cut-off frequency of 198 kHz i.e. above this the signal drops at 6 dB per decade i.e. it's a low pass filter. You were aiming for a bandwidth of maybe 400 MHz and you are crippled at anything above 200 kHz. Even if the feedback resistor were 80 kohm the BW would still only be 2 MHz.

Summary - alter your spec or hugely adjust your expectations.

It's also worth spending an hour or two using [ADI's photodiode design wizard](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/photodiode/). Even if you don't use one of their devices you can learn a lot by experimenting with it.

Comment: Kindly find an edit, I have a wide gap between pulses

Comment: The wide gap makes no difference to my bandwidth calculation. You still have to handle a 2ns rise, a 10ns hold and a 2ns fall. Just because I assumed it repeated every 24 ns was just for my convenience for working out the bandwidth required.

Comment: thanks for valuable points,the example you have shown deals with a large area photo diode in my case its only 1mm2 photo diode and its capacitance being not more than 12pF, yes your point on FET input is right and i am particular on that while selecting opamp. i will soon update my photo diode equivalent also, with which i am facing problem to simulate

Comment: Read my edits and note that for the bandwidth you want, 12pF is is a skyscraper. It's all down to noise gain so I suggest you get to grips with this and lower your expectations of speed and input dynamic range.

Comment: TIA idea is toast ! :(

Comment: i feel there are two problems here slewrate and dynamic voltage range, if i go for opamps like http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths3202.pdf these may solve my problem

Comment: The problem is noise gain not slewrate. Also, the op-amp you linked is a current feedback amp and not suitable (I think) as a TIA. I'm going to add another edit to my answer regarding op-amp open loop bandwidth and how it being limited might help a bit.

Comment: CFAs can be used as TIAs and in fact that might be useful toward the high end of the photocurrent range OP specifies. But their current noise specifications aren't anything to shout about because of the low inverting input impedance.

Comment: Actually, to me, 50 nA seems low more than 50 mA seems high. Most photodiodes will produce about 0.5 A/W, so to have an incident optical power of 100 nW (versus a pulse power of, at the very least, 10s of kW for a pulsed laser) sounds a little unrealistic. If it really is correct but the objective is just to detect the laser pulse rather than quantitatively measure it, an avalanche photodiode would do the job. Your answer is excellent but I think currently suffers from an underspecified question regarding the application.

Comment: @OleksandrR. currently i have no empirical data, what do you think will be min and max peak power that will be incident on a photo diode in case of LRF and LTD applications

Comment: @kakeh I don't know what LTD stands for, but for a laser rangefinder the amount of optical power you have to work with obviously depends on the distance you're measuring and what you're pointing at. It might indeed be as low as 100 nW in such an application, although hard to say without further detail. But as I said, you really don't need to quantitatively measure the pulse shape and amplitude for this; all you need to know is the round-trip time, and merely detecting the pulse is sufficient for that. An avalanche photodiode is very sensitive and should respond quickly enough.

Comment: @oleksandr R. Here in my case I am a warning system for all kind of lasers. Namely laser range finders and laser target designators and beam riders.in range of 5km to 500m

Comment: @kakeh how do you tell laser light apart from, and in the presence of, any other bright light? It is coherent, yes, but how can one determine this at the detector? It seems to me that you would need an interferometer, in which case the photodetector is the least of your worries.

Comment: @OleksandrR. i can discriminate it from the property of frequency, most of the non coherent sources are slowly varying i will have a 5Mhz HPF, am i wrong?

Comment: @kakeh in my opinion this will not be robust in the natural environment, although it depends on your tolerance for false detections. Anyway, comments under this answer are not the best place to have this discussion. Please feel free to refine your requirements and post a new question giving much more detail about what it is exactly that you're trying to accomplish and under what constraints.

Comment: @Andyaka i have changed my mind and decided to not to use TIA because, its failing to cover a wide range, a simple resistor in series may solve my problem !? where i will provide a gain of 10K later(50nA will be 50mV which is close to my threshold and 100mA is 5V input to comparator), any way if high current is output from diode the opamp output gets saturated and still i can read the pulse width with out fail, or am i thinking completely wrong ? or underestimating noise in case of non TIA, for this i found AD8003(1.6GHz and 4.3kV/us) to be suitable, but its a CFA, did i misunderstood anything

Comment: @Andyaka am i calculating properly ? if opamp has input noise 2nV/rtHz then at 100MHz its 20uV, now noise gain is 1+(Rf/Ri), as the Ri = photo diode impedance at 100MHz is lets say 200ohm, my noise gain is arround 5 if Rf is 800ohm per stage, on total its 25 noise gain, now the 20uV would be 500uV right ?

Comment: 2nV/rtHz over 100MHz is 20 uV. Noise gain for 1st stage would peak around 5 but 2nd stage won't be as bad because it doesn't have to consider photodiode capacitance. You should be able to design 2nd stage with very little increase in noise for that stage.

Comment: i have discussed these problems with my clients and came to 100nA - 10mA range, here to instead of sensing 10nA i should go for using some APD kind of diodes

Comment: So, do you now have the "tools" to work out if this is possible?

Comment: @Andyaka i have tried to realize the circuit on a board and the results have few problems please find them here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300498/eliminating-those-unwanted-op-amptia-outputs