# Cascading Op Amps for Phototransistor Output Conditioning

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, signal, instrumentation-amplifier

I am working on a project in which I am using an IR phototransistor to detect changing low levels of light. Currently with very high load resistance I can get a reading of 40-60 mV but I would like to stretch this out to approx 0 - 3.3 V so I have designed cascading op amps to do so. The issue being now, I'm not sure where to put the load resistor. The resistor determines the sensitivity but when placed in conjunction with the cascading amps the signal of the transistor goes to 0 V. Any suggestions? I have attached a rough schematic. Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNGWE.png)

Comment: I think you need a photodiode, not a phototransistor (which will also require a different circuit). Also, I think you have a typo with 3.3mV.

Comment: Normally one uses a TIA op amp config for high GBW.  What is your spec for GBW? I would use a low cost daylight blocking IR PD for normal levels which is very consistent and has none of the wide  variance issues due to hFE in PT's. Load R affects gain and BW inversely

Comment: Do you need to tolerate SUNLIGHT? or 60Hz? If so, a DC_nulling feedback approach is needed.

Comment: Why in the world do you have that 4.7k/50 ohm combination? It will reduce the voltage to the phototransistor by a factor of 100.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast My apologies, in my haste I drew that part of the schematic wrong. That divider produces the reference voltage for the voltage subtractor op amp. The transistor receives 3.3V

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I am not reading the current, I am reading the voltage output of the phototransistor.

Comment: @Toor we've tested photodiodes but for my application the phototransistor is more ideal

Comment: @RyanB That seems highly unlikely. It seems much more likely you weren't using the photodiode properly  Did you actually use a transimpedance amplifier circuit with the photodiode? You need to use those with photodiodes. If you were testing photodiodes with a TIA, okay, but if you weren't then you need to revisit photodiodes.
http://www.ti.com/tool/TIPD176

Comment: @Toor what makes you think the photodiode is ideal?

Comment: Photodiodes are faster (higher bandwidth), lower noise, more linear, and have a larger dynamic range. They also tend to have better characterization. The main advantage of a phototransistor is that it's simpler to use since it has higher gain so you don't need so much amplification. But  your phototransistor amplifier circuit is already a lot bigger than a TIA so it's a moot point.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying

Comment: @Ryan PT's are never ideal but they are cheap.  If you haven't used a TIA and PD before, you ought to if gain bandwidth is what you need.  Cascading is easy in dual or quad OA's. PD's are usually << 10% tolerance in mA/mW whereas PT's due to hFE with > 2:1 ratio in gain. Also Measuring V across a resistor is actually measuring current.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 what do I need to take into consideration when selecting a TIA?

Comment: Choose OA to suit your specs.  eg https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229866/selecting-a-tia-and-using-it-for-60db-dynamic-range

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 thanks for the help!

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa659.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that, by "nothing", you mean a level about 1/10 of your raw reading. The two 100k resistors on the input of the first op amp produce a 200k resistance in parallel with the 2M resistor. Since the phototransistor has a current output, the voltage across the new load will be about 1/10 the original, or something like 5 mV.

EDIT - You can try something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu7RZ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this will not give the exact zero of your original circuit. I assume that your offset is caused by a) leakage in the phototransistor, and b) op amp offset. In principle, if your original gives 0 volts for 0 light, the new circuit will give about 3 mV. You can adjust this by varying R2.

Comment: Yep you're totally right. Is there a way I can bring the signal of the phototransistor to the input of the op amp without that? I would switch to the diode and TIA but I don't exactly have the time

Comment: @RyanB - See edit.

Comment: how'd you come up with this configuration?

Comment: the idea with the previous was to take the signal and stretch it from say 30-50 mv to 0 - 3.3 V

Comment: @RyanB - In your circuit, the left-hand op amp and its associated 4 100k resistors form a unity-gain differential amp which subtracts about 3 mV from the raw load resistor voltage (ignoring the extra loading effects that I pointed out). This is followed by a non-inverting amp with gain equaling 165. I've maintained the gain, and used the 3 mV directly on the feedback network. If you want less gain, choose a different set of resistors. For instance, if you want 30 mV to produce 3.3 volts, you need a gain of 110, so the 164k resistor should be 109k.

Comment: If you don't want a 3 mV offset, that makes things easier, and the 1k gets tied directly to ground. I had no idea why you wanted the offset, but I tried to maintain the functionality of your circuit.

Comment: ok I see. I wanted the offset so that it would bring my lowest signal to 0 and then for the largest reading bring it to 3.3V